# Python function inputting variables into strings

Tags: python, excel, function, xlsxwriter

I have outputted a pandas df into an excel file using xlsxwriter.  I'm trying to create a totals row at the top. To do so, I'm trying to create a function that dynamically populates the totals based off the column I choose.

Here is an example of what I'm intending to do:

```
worksheet.write_formula('G4', '=SUM(G4:G21)')
#G4 = Where total should be placed
```

I need this to be a function because the row counts can change (summation range should be dynamic), and I want there to be an easy way to apply this formula to various columns.

Therefore I've come up with the following:

```
def get_totals(column):
    start_row = '4' #row which the totals will be on
    row_count = str(tl_report.shape[0]) #number of rows in the table so I can sum up every row.  
    return (worksheet.write_formula(str(column+start_row),"'=SUM("+str(column+start_row)+":"+str(column+row_count)+")'") )
```

When running get_totals("G") it just results in 0. I'm suspecting it has to do with the STR operator that I had to apply because its adding single quotes to the formula, and therefore rendering it incorrectly.

However I cannot take the str operator out because I cannot concatenate INTs apparently?

Maybe I'm coding this all wrong, new to python, any help appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE]().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [5,6,7,8],
                    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow = 2)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

def get_totals(start_row, sum_column, column1='A', column2='B'):
    for row in range(start_row,df.shape[0]+start_row):
        worksheet.write_formula(f'{sum_column}{row}', f'=SUM({column1}{row},{column2}{row})')

get_totals(4, 'C')

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also just for anyone in the future reading this, this is a great document that outlines string variable methods: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases XlsxWriter methods support two forms of notation to designate the position of cells: Row-column notation and A1 notation.

Row-column notation uses a zero based index for both row and column while A1 notation uses the standard Excel alphanumeric sequence of column letter and 1-based row. For example:

```
(6, 2)      # Row-column notation.
('C7')      # The same cell in A1 notation.
```

So for your case you could do the following and set the row-column values programatically (you may have to adjust by -1 to get zero indexing):

```
worksheet.write_formula(start_row, start_column, '=SUM(G4:G21)')
```

For the formula you could use of of XlsxWriter's [utility functions](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions):

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_range 

my_range = xl_range(3, 6, 20, 6)  # G4:G21
```